# How to delay computed properties to recomputed themselves in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

This question is come up with **Component Example** from the homepage of Ember.js, here's the code:

```
App.GravatarImageComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  size: 200,
  email: '',

  gravatarUrl: function() {
    var email = this.get('email'),
        size = this.get('size');

    return 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + hex_md5(email) + '?s=' + size;
  }.property('email', 'size')
});
```

When I try this example I noticed that everytime I input a character the browser will fire a request to get the avatar. If my email address have 30 characters, there will be 30 times requests got fired until the right one was returned from the server. I think this is too inefficient, isn't it?

After digging out the guides, I didn't find there is a way to solve this problem, so I was wondering: is this possible to delay re-compute a computed property for, say, like 1000ms? or is there a better way to deal with this type of scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can debounce it, which gives you a similar feeling of it reacting without having to do anything other than typing:

```
App.GravatarImageComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  size: 200,
  email: '',
  fetchEmail:'',

  watchEmail: function(){
    Em.run.debounce(this, this.setEmail, 400)
  }.observes('email'),

  setEmail: function(){
    this.set('fetchEmail', this.get('email'));
  },

  gravatarUrl: function() {
    var email = this.get('fetchEmail'),
        size = this.get('size');

    return 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + md5(email) + '?s=' + size;
  }.property('fetchEmail', 'size')
});
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lacefi/1/edit

Comment: Em is an alias of Ember.

Answer (score 4):

I had to put a debouncer on my observer to limit execution of my actual business logic in one of my project.

In this case, you can change your computed property `gravatarUrl` to normal property and move logic to build url on a observer, which observes `email` and `size` and update `gravatarUrl`, and then simply put a debouncer on your observer. I haven’t tested below code but here is the idea:

```
App.GravatarImageComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  size: 200,
  email: '',

  gravatarUrl: '',

  gravObserver: function() {
    Ember.run.debounce(this, this.updateGravUrl, 1000);

  }.observes('email', 'size'),

  updateGravUrl: function(){
    var email = this.get('email'),
        size = this.get('size');

  this.set('gravatarUrl','http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + hex_md5(email) + '?s=' + size);
  }
});
```

Comment: I like your answer as well as kingpin2k's, actually I will choose yours in real project, but @kingpin2k's answer is best suit for this question, so I made my choice, thank you anyway!

Comment: NP i would have also done the same. Probably we were typing our andwers on the same time ;-)