# How to properly add a “debounce” to the Gravatar component example on the EmberJS homepage?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

So I’m teaching myself EmberJS and things are going well. Thanks to questions and answers presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33797065/117259) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33773650/117259) I’m past the initial headaches. My environment is as follows:

- **Ember CLI version:** 1.13.12
- **Node JS version:** 4.2.2
- **NPM (Node Package Manager) version:** 2.14.10
- **Watchman:** 4.1.0

I’m now revisiting the [“Components” example on the official EmberJS homepage](http://emberjs.com). The simple code example is presented as such; adjusted for the EmberCLI structure of course:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  size: 200,
  email: '',

  gravatarUrl: Ember.computed('email', 'size', function() {
    var email = this.get('email').toLowerCase(),
        size = this.get('size');

    return 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + md5(email) + '?s=' + size;
  })

});
```

The problem with this is it attempts to fetch the Gravatar URL on each keypress which is expensive and noise for a a fronted application. Instead I would like to delay the fetch of the data until typing has stopped. Based on the posts I have found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24981752/how-to-delay-computed-properties-to-recomputed-themselves-in-ember-js) as well as [here](http://blog.yodersolutions.com/debounce-search-filter-in-emberjs/) and [here](http://pboutin.net/frontend/2014/10/10/emberjs_gravatar.html) the key seems to be to use [`debounce`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_debounce) to delay the process. So far so good. So looking at those linked examples and the official EmberJS example I whipped this up; but I’m not too hot about it:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  email: '',
  size: 200,
  delay: 500,

  gravatarUrl: Ember.computed('email', 'size', function () {
    Ember.run.debounce(this, this.gravatarUrlSetValue, this.get('delay'));
  }),

  watchEmail: function () {
    Ember.run.debounce(this, this.gravatarUrlSetValue, this.get('delay'));
  }.observes('email', 'size'),

  gravatarUrlSetValue: function() {
    var email = this.get('email').toLowerCase();
    var size = this.get('size');

    this.set('gravatarUrl', 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + md5(email) + '?s=' + size);
  }

});
```

First and foremost, this works. But it seems odd to me that I have two `Ember.run.debounce` calls within two functions. Shouldn’t they be combined in some way? Also, note I am using [the suggestion from `lame_coder`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24983040/117259) which replaces this return command:

```
return 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + md5(email) + '?s=' + size
```

With this:

```
this.set('gravatarUrl', 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + md5(email) + '?s=' + size);
```

That too seems messy since am I essentially overwriting a method with a value. I mean this all works, but is this just a kludge that could be handled better? For example, the `watchEmail` function is never explicitly called, but seems to be needed if not mainly for the `.observes('email', 'size')` aspect. What can be done to clean this up and get it to function as desired with the `debounce` logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I was able to answer this myself. The [code provided in `sbatson5`’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33814892/117259) works fine now, but the rejiggering that solution seems to need seems trade one complexity issue for another. There’s nothing particularly oddball about this overall example and issue that would require that kind of recoding.

My instincts also told me that this is all simpler than I thought. So I decided: Just call `this.watchEmail();` directly from the `gravatarUrl()` function. Knowing that I was able to restructure the code from what I had before to this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  email: '',
  size: 200,
  delay: 500,

  gravatarUrl: function () {
    this.watchEmail();
  }.property('email', 'size'),

  watchEmail: function () {
    Ember.run.debounce(this, this.gravatarUrlSetValue, this.get('delay'));
  }.observes('email'),

  gravatarUrlSetValue: function() {
    const email = this.get('email').toLowerCase();
    const size = this.get('size');

    // console.log(this.get('email'));
    this.set('gravatarUrl', 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + md5(email) + '?s=' + size);
  }

});
```

While there are still three core functions here, the logic is a tad cleaner. I also read up on [“computed properties” in the official EmberJS documentation](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/object-model/computed-properties/) and note that the `gravatarUrl: Ember.computed('email', 'size', function () {` I had in place originally is considered an “alternate invocation” method. And the actual default/preferred way of handling computed values is to attach `.property('email', 'size')` to a function instead. It looks and reads cleaner and is easier to parse.

So this satisfies my needs. If anyone has a simpler way to invoke a `debounce` in a case like this, please feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As an overview, we have input where the user enters an email. That email controls the image that is shown at the top of the template.

I would start by adding an action to your input:

```
<img src={{gravatarUrl}}>
<div class="email-input">
  {{input type="email" value=initialEmail placeholder="Enter your Gravatar e-mail" key-up="updateEmail"}}
</div>
```

Notice that we also set the value to something different to essentially overwrite the current two-way binding.  We can then write our own debounce that sets this value.

So, in your component you can still have that same CP, but add an action with a debounce:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
const { Component, computed, get, set, run } = Ember;

export default Component.extend({
  size: 200,
  email: '',
  initialEmail: '',

  gravatarUrl: computed('email', 'size', function() {
    const email = get(this, 'email').toLowerCase(),
      size = get(this, 'size');

    return `http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/${md5(email)}?s=${size}`;
  }),
  actions: {
    updateEmail() {
      run.debounce(() => {
        const newEmail = get(this, 'initialEmail');
        set(this, 'email', newEmail);
      }, 500); // or whatever time period you want
    }
  }
});
```

I can think of a few ways to do this, but this is an approach I have used when I wanted to have a CP update after a short period and not every time someone typed.

**EDIT:** Missed the arrow function on my initial post and should have used `get` to pull in initial email. Here is [an *Ember Twiddle* example](https://ember-twiddle.com/1466d2a317307b7bcdfc?numColumns=1).

Note that I can’t pull the in the `md5()` method, so use `0cf15665a9146ba852bf042b0652780a` as the email and you will see the “toaster” image appear after 500ms.